# Await all HTTP request body chunks before moving on

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm developing a man-in-the-middle proxy that will let the user see and modify HTTP and HTTPS requests before they leave the client and responses before they arrive at the client. The code I'm working on is working, but I don't know if it's the right or beast way to achieve this behaviour. I'm waiting for all request and response chunks before moving on the the next step.

Browsing with the proxy on is clearly slower, although this is not a problem to the application I'll use this proxy on. Below is the code I'm using to wait for all body chunks before performing the next step.

````js
let requestBody: Buffer

    try {
      requestBody = await this.collectMessageBody(req)
    } catch (error) {
      req.destroy(new ProxyError('Error while fetching request body', ErrorType.unknown, error))
      return
    }

    let modifiedRequest: any

    try {
      // Send the intercepted request to the client before forwarding to its destination
      modifiedRequest = await this.interceptHandler('request', request, response)
    } catch (error) {
      req.destroy(new ProxyError('Request dropped by the client', ErrorType.denied, error))
      return
    }
    // Handle the response from the forwarded request. The logic is similar to above but can be ignored to this question scope
    const responseHandler = async (serverResponse: http.IncomingMessage) => this.receiveResponse(request, response, serverResponse, res)
    // Creates the request that will be sent to the final destination using http.request(...)
    const forwardedRequest = Router.forward(modifiedRequest, responseHandler)
    forwardedRequest.on('error', error => this.emit('error', error))

    // Write the original request body to the forwarded one
    forwardedRequest.write(requestBody)
    // Send the request
    forwardedRequest.end()


private collectMessageBody(incomingMessage: http.IncomingMessage): Promise<Buffer> {
    return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      let bodyBuffers: Buffer[] = []

      incomingMessage.on('data', chunk => bodyBuffers.push(chunk))
      incomingMessage.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(bodyBuffers)))
      incomingMessage.on('error', error => reject(error))
    })
  }
```
````